# Finding last Sunday and going 4 weeks backward every week in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I have a SAS job that runs every Thursday, but sometime it need to run on Wednesday, and maybe Tuesday evening.  The job collects some data in 4 week intervals up until the closest Sunday. For example, today we have 19Mar2015, and I need data until 15Mar2015.

```
data get_some_data;
  set all_the_data;
  where date >= '16Feb2015' and date <= '15Mar2015';
run;
```

Next week I have to manually change the date parameters too

```
data get_some_data;
  set all_the_data;
  where date >= '23Feb2015' and date <= '22Mar2015';
run;
```

Anyway I can automate this?

Comment: Look up the documentation for the `intnx` and `today` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll expand on the suggestion from @user667489 as it could take you a while to work it out.  The key is to use the `week` time interval, which by default starts on a Sunday (you can change this with a shift index, read [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003065889.htm#a003065892) for further details)

So your query just needs to be :

```
where intnx('week',today(),-4)<date<=intnx('week',today(),0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INTNX` function to regress the date back to last Sunday:

```
data get_some_data;
  set all_the_data;
  lastsun=intnx('week',today(),0);
  /*where date >= '23Feb2015' and date <= '22Mar2015';*/
  where date between lastsun-27 and lastsun;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the last sunday date using weekday function and then using INTNX get the 4 week back date from that sunday date. Check the below ref code :

```
    data mydata;
    input input_date YYMMDD10.;
    /* Loop to get the last sunday date, do the processing
       and get out of loop */
    do i =0 to 7 until(last_sunday_date>0);
        /* Weekday Sunday=1 */
        if weekday(sum(input_date,-i))=1 then do; 
            last_sunday_date=sum(input_date,-i);  
          /* INTNX to get the 4 week back date */
            my_4_week_start=intnx('week',last_sunday_date,-4); 
       end;
    end;
    format input_date last_sunday_date my_4_week_start yymmdd10.;
    datalines4;
    2015-03-01
    2015-03-07
    2015-03-14
    2015-03-21
    2015-03-28
    2015-04-05
    2015-04-13
    2015-04-20
    ;;;;
    run;
    proc print data=mydata;run;
```

let me know if this helps!